# SharePoint Feed Remove Unliked entry

Tags: sharepoint-online, my-profile

I am creating a list of my "likes" on the home page of a SharePoint online intranet, I can see list of all my likes but if I unlike a document,  I want to remove the like entry.

Is this possible? I cannot use "Follow" feature because I have to provide like functionality on pages and follow does not work on pages.